# How do I do String replace in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I have the following list of tuples and a string

```
type M a = [(String, String)]
m = [
    ("x", "a car"),
    ("y", "a animal")
]
s = "this is x and y"
```

I am trying to

`strRep m s` => "this is a car and a animal"

So this is my attempt so far

```
import Data.List.Utils

strRep :: (Show a) => M -> String -> String
strRep [] s = s
strRep (m:ms) s = replace (fst m) (snd m) s : strRep ms s
```

The above code returns a list of string.  I cant quite figure out the proper way to do loop here.

Comment: Can ou show your imports?  Where are you getting `replace` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where `replace` is coming from in your example above.  But... assuming it exists, and does what you expect, you should be able to remove the cons `(:)` from your `strRep` function, and instead pass the result of replace into the next run of strRep, like so:

```
strRep :: (Show a) => M -> String -> String
strRep [] s = s
strRep (m:ms) s = strRep ms (replace (fst m) (snd m) s)
```

Now, instead of returning a list of strings, each a version with one thing replaced.  You are iteratively replacing each string, passing the new strings on for the next replacement.

Comment: Oops, replace is from Data.List.Utils

Answer (score 2):

Looping in haskell can almost always be realized using a fold.
So in your example you need to build your result by consecutively replacing strings taken from your mapping.

Let's use a strict fold:

```
import Data.List(foldl')
```

Then your `strRep` would look like:

```
strRep :: M -> String -> String
strRep m input = foldl' replace input m
```

Or a little shorter:

```
strRep = flip $ foldl' replace
```

Dealing with `String`s is performing rather poorly. A better alternative is to deal with `Text` from `Data.Text`.
Then `replace` is rather straight forward:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T

replace :: String -> (String,String) -> String
replace s (a,b) = let [ss,aa,bb] = [T.pack x | x <- [s,a,b]] in
  T.unpack $ T.replace aa bb ss
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace m w = case (lookup w m) of
                          Just w' -> w'
                          otherwise -> w

strRep :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String
strRep m s = unwords $ map (replace m) $ words s
```

Answer (score 0):

Another different way to solve your problem

```
type M = [(String , String)]

m = [("x", "a car"),
     ("y", "a animal")]

lookUp :: String->M ->String
lookUp a lst =  head ( [ value| (key ,value ) <- lst , key == a])


strRep :: String ->M->String
strRep input replacements = unwords ( map repAux ( words input))
   where
     poss = map fst replacements
     repAux :: String -> String
     repAux x
       | elem x poss = lookUp x replacements
       | otherwise = x
```