# String replace using map compilation error

Tags: string, haskell, dictionary, replace

I am new to Haskell, and trying to implement the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862277/5004298) to replace strings using a map. I am getting an error message during compilation that says

```
* Expecting one more argument to `StringMap'
  Expected a type, but `StringMap' has kind `* -> *'
* In the type signature:
    stringMapReplace :: (Show stringMap) => StringMap -> String -> String
```

I have tried searching, but the only answer I can find for the error is that I'm not clarifying what type `StringMap` is. However, I thought that is what `Show stringMap` was doing.

```
import Data.Map
import Data.Strings

type StringMap stringMap = [(String, String)]
myStringMap =
    [
        ("org1", "rep1"),
        ("org2", "rep2")
    ]

stringMapReplace :: (Show stringMap) => StringMap -> String -> String
stringMapReplace [] s = s
stringMapReplace (m:ms) s = strReplace ms (replace (fst m) (snd m) s)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter some text:"
    putStrLn =<< stringMapReplace myStringMap <$> toUpper getLine
```

Note: `strReplace` comes from `Data.Strings`

I don't know if there is anything else wrong with the code, as the compiler is only giving the error above right now. If you notice anything else right off, please feel free to mention (or leave it for me to debug later as practice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined the type synonym `StringMap` to take an (unused) type parameter `stringMap`. Type *synonyms*, as opposed to `newtype`, `data`, and GADT declarations, must always be *fully applied*. Thus every occurrence of `StringMap` must be have a parameter supplied, like `forall a . StringMap a`, `StringMap Int`, etc. In the signature of `stringMapReplace`, you do not give `StringMap` a parameter, hence the error.

Two options:

1. Change `StringMap` to `type StringMap = [(String, String)]`, because it doesn't need a parameter.
2. Give `StringMap` a parameter in the signature of `stringMapReplace`. What parameter, you ask? Any one, because it is ignored. For example, the following should work:

   ```
   stringMapReplace :: StringMap String -> String -> String
   ```

Comment: @chi Thanks. Fixed now.